Exclude a topic from wildcard topic on a mosquitto bridge
I have configured a bridge topic on a mosquitto broker with a wildcard like this:
topic sensor/# both 1

But I want to exclude a specific topic tree sensor/test/#. The sensor/test messages should be sent to any local subscriber but not over the bridge to the remote broker.
How can I do that?
I've asked my colleague ChatGPT and it suggested topic - sensor/test/# both. But this delivers an error:

Invalid bridge topic direction 'sensor/test/#'.


I think the only way to do this is by setting a local user on the bridge and then excluding a topic with an ACL. P.s. ChatGPT is making stuff up

But also it will depend on which side the message is coming from

@hardillb Since the test messages should still be subscribable on the bridge, do I have the exclude them by ACL on the remote broker?

Assuming you just don't want to forward sensor/test/# to the remote end of the bridge then I think something like the following should work.
mosquitto.conf
...
acl_file acls.conf

connection remote-bridge
address remote.example.com
local_username localBridge
topic sensor/# both 1

acls.conf
user localBridge
topic read sensor/#
topic deny sensor/test/#

If you want to stop sensors/test/# from being sent from the remote broker, then this will require remote_username in the bridge and matching ACL rules on the remote broker.

This seems to work only if the message is published by localBridge. However then the topic cannot be subscribed locally any more. If another user publishes to sensor/test/# the message is sent to the remote broker ignoring the configuration of localBridge.

You will need to add some global acl rules

If allow_anonymous=false only user specific ACL rules are possible. For the publishing user the rule is: topic readwrite # . For the bridge user as you suggested. It seems the local_username in the bridge config is  totally ignored. It makes no difference whether I specify a non existent user or the actual bridge user.
